# yup .test validation prevent other rules from execution in the schema

Tags: javascript, yup

I have a custom test, but when its implemented inside a schema, it stops the whole schema, even I already have `abortEarly: true` for the schema itself.

I defined the test like this:

```
const dateFormatRequired = () => yup
                .string()
                .test({
                    name: 'date-format-bd',
                    message:'Date format should be MM/DD/YYY',
                    test: (value, cotext) => {
                        console.log(value)
                        const dateInList = value.split('-');
                        const yearHasCorrectDigit = dateInList[0].length === 4;
                        const monthAndDayHasCorrectDigit = dateInList[1].length == 2 && dateInList[2].length == 2;
                        return yearHasCorrectDigit && monthAndDayHasCorrectDigit;
                    },
                    params: {
                        abortEarly: false
                    }
                })
```

Schema itself like this:

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
                dateOfBirth: dateFormatRequired(),
                gender: isRequiredOnly,
            );
schema
   .validateSync({...some values match my data shape}, { abortEarly: false })
```

When the `dateFormatRequired` failed, the whole schema's `error.inner` will be empty.

Any suggestions how can I debug this further or a solution?